# How do I get all available colors displayed on the product page?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm building a shopping website. I have my database design set up as below:

```
tblProducts       tblSizes   tblColors   tblImages    tblSpecific_Products
id                id         id          id           id        
product_name      size       color       image        product_id  (FK)                                            
style_code                                            size_id (FK)                                                                                                                                        
price                                                 color_id (FK)                                                                                                       
                                                      image_id (FK)
```

Can someone please tell me how do I display all available colors on the general products page?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are asking to query all available colors of a specific product. In that case, if you go through SQL tutor you will get by yourself.

Here is how it can be done,

```
SELECT color FROM tblColors WHERE id IN (SELECT color_id FROM tblSpecificProducts WHERE product_id=<YOUR-PRODUCT-ID>)
```

If you want it on general Product Display Page, where for each product display all available colors, then do iterate over all product Id's.

Comment: Thanks Arun. I actually want all available colors for each product to display on general product display page (not on a specific product page). Right now I only can get one color for one product, but not all colors if that product has more than one color. If I can have this done, then I know how to work on my specific product page.  Can you please help?

Comment: Here is my query on products table.                                     SELECT id,product_name,style_code,color,price,category FROM products WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY date_added DESC.               It is for category.php page which displays all general products.                          I searched and tried for days but couldn't figure out how to have all colors display on this page. :(

Comment: No Comments on what you are asking for. I suggest you to learn SQL and understand yourself what you are asking for & what I answered... I wonder how even your query works anyhow, to get list of product ID's which can be iterated as I said you can use "SELECT id FROM tblProducts" Use result of this & iterate over query being answered. I do not understand sorting by date_added, as I do not see any date attribute.

Comment: Sorry to make you confused Arun. My products table includes id(PK),product_name(UK),style_code(UK),color,price,category(dresses,tops,bottoms),description and date_added. I thought it was not important to list them all but I'm wrong. Sorry. My category.php begins with if (isset($_GET['category'])){ include_once("db_connect.php"); $category=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z]#i', ' ', $_GET['category']); $sql = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY date_added DESC");

Answer (score 0):

You can just `join` your tables:

```
SELECT color
FROM tblSpecific_Products
JOIN tblColors
ON tblSpecific_Products.color_id = tblColors.id AND
   tblSpecific_Products.product_id = <yourvalue>;
```

If you want to get all colors of all products, then you can do this:

```
SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(color) AS colors
FROM tblSpecific_Products
LEFT JOIN tblColors
ON tblSpecific_Products.color_id = tblColors.id
GROUP BY product_id;
```

And then you will get pairs of two items per record, the first field being the numerical id of the product, the second being a comma-separated textual list of the colors. In your PHP code, you can `explode(',', $theValue)` in order to separate the comma-separated color list into array elements that you can loop.